# Fill missing values using MissForest algorithm on each group in column in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, fillna

I have a time series data of about **4000 patients** that has missing values and I want to impute NaN values using **MissForest algorithm in Python** on each patient file separately.

The data looks like this:

| HR | Resp | P_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 72.0 | 18.0 | 1 |
| NaN | 15.0 | 1 |
| 80.0 | NaN | 1 |
| NaN | 16.0 | 1 |
| 79.5 | NaN | 1 |
| NaN | 19.0 | 2 |
| 79.5 | 22.5 | 2 |
| NaN | NaN | 2 |
| NaN | 16.0 | 2 |
| 85.0 | NaN | 3 |
| NaN | 14.5 | 3 |
| 76.4 | NaN | 3 |
| NaN | NaN | 4 |
| 80.5 | 19.5 | 4 |
| 75.3 | 18.0 | 4 |
| NaN | 21.5 | 4 |

Now, I want to impute NaN values within the patients data in column based on P_ID. Like it will impute **P_ID = 1**, then **P_ID = 2** and so on. Not the imputation on the whole column. The code I am using will impute NaN on whole column of all patients, not in individual Patients column, then the next patient.

```
imputer = MissForest(max_iter=12, n_jobs=-1)
X_imputed = imputer.fit_transform(df)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(X_imputed)
df1.head()
```

I did the Mean Imputation within patient itself using the following code, but can't figure out how I can use it for MissForest.

```
for i in ['HR','Resp']:
    df[i] = df[i].fillna(df.groupby('P_ID')[i].transform('mean'))
```

**One solution** is **I make 4000 data frames** of each patient, **impute them using MissForest**, then **combine them together**. That will be a hectic task. So I want a solution with looping over the entire dataframe. Kindly help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following to go through the `P_ID`s, then apply the `MissForest` only on the filtered values:

```py
for idx in df["ID"].unique():
    # check if the column "Resp" is all nan
    if not df[df.ID == idx].Resp.any():
        df.loc[df.ID == idx, "Resp"] = df.loc[df.ID == idx, "Resp"].fillna(0)
    imputer = MissForest(max_iter=12, n_jobs=-1)
    x_imp = imputer.fit_transform(df[df.ID == idx])
    df.loc[df.ID == idx, :] = x_imp
```

This gives you:

```py
|    |      HR |    Resp |   ID |
|---:|--------:|--------:|-----:|
|  0 | 72      | 18      |    1 |
|  1 | 79.5942 | 15      |    1 |
|  2 | 80      | 15.4617 |    1 |
|  3 | 79.5942 | 16      |    1 |
|  4 | 79.5    | 15.4617 |    1 |
|  5 | 79.5    | 19      |    2 |
|  6 | 79.5    | 22.5    |    2 |
|  7 | 79.5    | 18.9217 |    2 |
|  8 | 79.5    | 16      |    2 |
|  9 | 85      | 14.5    |    3 |
| 10 | 80.786  | 14.5    |    3 |
| 11 | 76.4    | 14.5    |    3 |
| 12 | 79.148  | 20.885  |    4 |
| 13 | 80.5    | 19.5    |    4 |
| 14 | 75.3    | 18      |    4 |
| 15 | 79.148  | 21.5    |    4 |
```

Comment: it worked. Thanks. However there is a slight issue. It raised value error something like "One or more columns have all NaN values". Means when it reached a patient, and it had all NaNs in one column, it stopped imputation and raised the error. How I can tackle that?

Comment: What should happen in this case, should the values be set to `-1`? If you find my answer helpful, I'd appreciate if you accept it

Comment: In that case, the patient with a column with all NaN values be imputed using 0. Can you please modify your answer so I can give it a try?

Comment: Which column is all `NaN`s, I assume `HR`? I updated the answer assuming `HR`...

Comment: Well this is just the dummy data I provided here for ease of replication and solution. The Resp column had all NaNs when it raised the errors.